# How to run Selenium IDE scripts in Selenium RC using PHPUnit?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am able to make selenium scripts in the selenium IDE and also able to export it in PHPUnit.
I also installed PHPUnit(Which i guess is installed correctly) and the selenium-rc server(Which ran perfectly).
Then i ran those scripts using the command: 'PHPUnit Testname.php' which gave nothing as an output.
If anyone knows anything regarding running these PHPUnit scripts, please throw in some light.
    Thanks.............

Answer (score 0):

The command to run the tests (without playing with filters etc...) includes the test suite name from which it deduces the filename.  So,

```
phpunit Testname
```

rather than

```
phpunit Testname.php
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply ... i tried the above command also....but still there is no output....can you please suggest some other way...

Comment: @ankur On the new command prompt enter the specific directory location of the file and enter phpunit xyz.php

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your selenium RC is running. e.g. (java -jar selenium-server.jar)

Try saving this test as :

**exampleTest.php**

Then run it through the command line as :

**phpunit exampleTest.php**

Hope this helps.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class exampleTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com');
  }

  public function testexampleTest()
  { 
    echo "Navigating browser to stackoverflow.com ...";
    $this->open('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
    $this->waitForPageToLoad('30000');
    echo "Made it to stackoverflow!";
    $this->sleep(5);
    echo "Test Complete";
  }
}
?>
```